My HP laserjet1000 does not work after upgrading to 24.04.1
My HP laserjet1000 does not work after upgrading from 20.04.1.
I admit that this is an older (and dependable) HP printer,
but it worked fine before the upgrade.
***************************************************************
**The HP device manager says** 
"Unable to open device hp:/usb/hp_LaserJet_1000?serial=0."
********************************************************************

**When I ran {hp-setup}
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)

error: No devices found on bus: usb


From the HP Device Manager Printing Status:


When I ran {hp-check}
|Gtk-Message: 07:02:27.735: 
Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
warning: ubuntu-24.04 version is not supported. 
Using ubuntu-23.04 versions dependencies to verify and install...


| SYSTEM INFO |
 Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 10:34:03 UTC 2024 GNU/Linux
 Host: 2022
 Proc: 6.8.0-40-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul  5 10:34:03 UTC 2024 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: ubuntu 24.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.23.12
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
warning: HPLIP-Installation: 
Auto installation is not supported for ubuntu distro  24.04 version 
Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  
Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.23.12
[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d

# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.

[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.23.12
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=yes
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=no
class-driver=no

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.22.6

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%
[fax]
email_address = 
voice_phone = 
[installation]
date_time = 09/23/24 07:02:29
version = 3.23.12
[last_used]
device_uri = "hp:/usb/hp_LaserJet_1000?serial=0"
printer_name = hp_LaserJet_1000
working_dir = 
[polling]
device_list = 
enable = false
interval = 5
[refresh]
enable = false
rate = 30
type = 1
[settings]
systray_messages = 0
systray_visible = 0
[upgrade]
last_upgraded_time = 1659236765
latest_available_version = 3.17.10
notify_upgrade = true
pending_upgrade_time = 0


 <Package-name> 
       <Package-Desc>  
    <Required/Optional> 
<Min-Version> 
<Installed-Version> 
<Status>  
 <Comment>


| External Dependencies |
error: cups
 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System      REQUIRED        1.1                          
INCOMPAT   'CUPS may not be installed or not running'
 gs                  
 GhostScript -
 PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            10.02.1         OK         -
Gtk-Message: 07:02:30.193: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Gtk-Message: 07:02:30.229: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.2.1           OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.14.10         OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.21.4          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.8             OK         -


| General Dependencies |
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               -    OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.39'         OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libavahi-dev         libavahi-dev                                                 REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.9.4           OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               3.0.13          OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.12.3          OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 error: python3-pyqt4-dbus PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         OPTIONAL        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4-dbus needs to be installed'
 error: python3-pyqt4 PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4 needs to be installed'
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.3.2           OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.6.1           OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.12.3          OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               10.2.0          OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             4.1.0           OK         -


| COMPILEDEP |
 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.7           OK         -
 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               13.2.0          OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.3             OK         -


| Python Extentions |
 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.23.12         OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.23.12         OK         -


| Scan Configuration |
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.23.12         OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.23.12         OK         -


| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
No Scanner found.


| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
No devices found.


| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
hp-LaserJet-1000
----------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/hp_LaserJet_1000?serial=0
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/hp-LaserJet-1000.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/hp-LaserJet-1000.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer hp-LaserJet-1000 now printing hp-LaserJet-1000-1843.  enabled sicfFilterChain: pdftopdf (PID 955328) exited with no errors.
warning: plug-in status: Version mismatch
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/usb/hp_LaserJet_1000?serial=0
error: Device not found
error: Communication status: Failed


| PERMISSION |

| SUMMARY |
Missing Required Dependencies
error: 'libcups2' package is missing/incompatible 

Missing Optional Dependencies
None

Plug-in Status
error: Plug-ins need to be installed

Total Errors: 4
Total Warnings: 1

Done.

I made sure CUPS is up-to-date
billschell@2022:~$ **{sudo apt install cups}**
[sudo] password for billschell: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
**cups is already the newest version (2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2).**
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.


HP says I need a BINARY PLUGIN
When I ran {hp-plugin}
billschell@2022:~$ {hp-plugin}

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)

Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.


HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread


I clicked "NEXT"

This notice also shows up


More from the Terminal
Checking for network connection...

error: Network connection not detected.
error: Failed to install Plugin.
error: The device you are trying to setup requires a binary plug-in. 
Some functionalities may not work as expected without plug-ins. 
Please run 'hp-plugin' as normal user to install plug-ins.
Visit http://hplipopensource.com for more infomation.


Run {hp-plugin} again
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
Checking for network connection...
error: Network connection not detected.
error: Network connection not detected.


Showing ports
Output of lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:3200 Dell Computer Corp. Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 024: ID 03f0:0517 HP, Inc LaserJet 1000
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

As you can see, the hp laserjet is detected.

Please use the {_} icon to format pasted text as code. Don't add extra lines or anything else.

Looks like an XY problem; network connection missing? And then; sudo apt install --reinstall hplip cups ?

Thank you for your consideration. I received 2 notices: "Device Communication Error 5102" and "Unable to open device"

@Bill Schell I am having the same problem with my HP printer and Ubuntu 24.04.01 upgrade. It appears to be a bug in the upgrade so I created a bug report. Refer to it for details

lol, I feel your pain. It consumed a good part of my weekend too!

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS- Add HP printer CUPS server Error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm giving up. I'm "burned out." I've spent probably 40 hours trying different suggestions over and over. I still have the same problems now as when I started. Some of the suggestions are too technical for me to understand, and i don't want to crash my computer. I will be buying another printer. it will probably not be an HP.

I completely understand your frustration! I also have a HP printer - (MFP M182nw).  I just now upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.5 and my HP printer still works fine. If you are really happy with your HP printer (As I am), I suggest you either wait for a fix in Ubuntu 24.04.1 or downgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.5. Unfortunately the latter would require a backup, clean install Ubuntu 22.04.5 and restore the backup .

I am going to wait until Ubuntu corrects it. @stumblebee Do you know how long a fix like this can take?

@Bill Schell
Not an ideal solution but its a work around. I email what ever document I want to print and then just print it from my phone.

@powerserg The bug fixes are mostly done by volunteers so no date is given for a anticipated fix. The more affected users, the more attention the bug will get (Which is currently 1 user). At Bill Schell - I recommend you also add yourself as a affected user by clicking on This bug affects 1 person. Does this bug affect you? and keep checking the status. From what I understand, the printer will work if you use a USB cable.

I use a USB cable, and it always worked until the last upgrade.

I had another cheap HP Deskjet printer 4100 series. new, still in the box. It's an older printer, but I was able to  connect it up and get working. The HP laserjet still does not work. It works with my Windows XP computer, but not with Ubuntu.

The HP DeskJet cartridge cost $28 for a very small cartridge, so I bought a brand-new Brother Monochrome laser printer (USB only) for only $100. It could only be set-up from the terminal, but the instructions were better than most. I'm Not a techi, but I was able to figure it out without too much trouble. :)
